# using ssp and sdp libraries shows bigger UI componant size

Tags: android, layout

I am using size dimen libraries for dp and sp. for responsive UI

```
 implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
 implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
```

it shows bigger size than usual

*for example*: If I used `48sdp` it takes around 64dp space or size.

how its take size?

Answer (score 2):

ssp and sdp libraries are libraries that will resize your elements (hence the different dps)  depending on the screen size and it is usually used to get consistent UI in different mobile sizes.
A few ways to achieve this is

1. When using ssp and sdp set the phone with the lowest size as the target device when designing
2. Use constraint layout and match constraint in conjunction with sdp and ssp .